# What is the best variable scope I should use in servlet operation

Tags: java, variables, servlets, static-methods, static-members

I am working on workflow management system.

Have one separate java class which contains logic method. One of this is:

```
public static in get_nxt_stg(int current_stg,int action)
{
}
```

and define static variable `cur_stg` and `nxt_stg`. used in servlet. call this method.

When multiple users log in and do some action these variables get not proper value. It seems like it is shared between all user requests.

What is best way to use variable in servlet, which is remain specific for that request?

Comment: Use only local variables. They won't be shared by different requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use static in such a way. If you need to share state, consider using the singleton pattern; but try to avoid static. Unwise use of "static" can turn into a nightmare (for example regarding unit testing).

In addition: it seems that you are a beginner with the Java language. But creating servlets is definitely a "advanced" java topic. I really recommend you to start learning more about Java as preparation for working on servlets. Otherwise the user of your server might have many unpleasant experiences ...

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. You should use Servlets only for the purpose of reading request parameters and sending responses. What you are trying to do, should be implemented in the Business layer of your application and if you have it implemented with EJBs, then your problem can easily be solved with an Stateful EJB.